# Can a generalized function be uniquely decomposed into singular and regular parts?

Tags: distribution-theory

Let $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of smooth functions with compact support and $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ the space of distributions (ie. continuous linear functionals on $\mathcal{D}$). There is a natural embedding $T: L^1_{\mathrm{loc.}}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$:
$$
  T(f) = \varphi \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \, \varphi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
  \qquad
  \forall f \in L^1_{\mathrm{loc.}} \quad
  \forall \varphi \in \mathcal{D}
$$
The space $T(L^1_{\mathrm{loc.}}) \subset \mathcal{D}'$ of all distributions representable by a locally integrable function is called the space of *regular distributions*, all other distributions are called *singular distributions*. My question is: **does every distribution $f \in \mathcal{D}'$ have a unique decomposition into the sum $f = f_{\mathrm{reg.}} + f_{\mathrm{sing.}}$of its regular and singular parts?**

---

I intuitively feel that this should be true, but struggle to define such a decomposition more precisely, let alone prove it. The first problem one encounters is that given a smooth function $g(x)$, $f = g + \delta \,$ has many possible decompositions:
$$
  f
  = \underbrace{0}_{\mathrm{reg.}} + \underbrace{g + \delta}_{\mathrm{sing.}} \;
  = \underbrace{\tfrac{1}{2} g}_{\mathrm{reg.}} + \underbrace{\tfrac{1}{2} g + \delta}_{\mathrm{sing.}}
  = \underbrace{g}_{\mathrm{reg.}} + \underbrace{\delta}_{\mathrm{sing.}}
  = \underbrace{2g}_{\mathrm{reg.}} \; \underbrace{ - g + \delta}_{\mathrm{sing.}}
$$
Obviously, the decomposition I want is $f_{\mathrm{reg.}} = g, \; f_{\mathrm{sing.}} = \delta$. Maybe a decomposition, where the support of $f_{\mathrm{sing.}}$ is equal to its [singular support](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularSupport.html) would be a good criterion? But I don't know, maybe there are distributions with non-discrete singular spectrum or something like that, when this approach would fail.

---

I know that there is a class of distributions called *distributions of order zero* that have a one-to-one correspondence with Radon measures ([Carlsson](http://www.math.chalmers.se/%7Ehasse/distributioner_eng.pdf), 2.6):
$$
  \forall T \in \mathcal{D}' \text{ of order 0 }
  \exists \text{ Radon measure } \mu
  \qquad
  T(\varphi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi \; \mathrm{d}\mu
  \qquad \forall \varphi \in \mathcal{D}
$$
Such a measure can be decomposed into $\mu_{\mathrm{reg.}}$ and $\mu_{\mathrm{sing.}}$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure by the [Lebesgue's decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem). But this doesn't tell me anything about the decomposition of distributions of general order.

Comment: What do you mean with "its complement" ? Try with $pv(1/x)$ to see the problem.

Comment: By "singular distribution" I mean every distribution that is not regular, I edited the question to make it more clear. I don't know how to decompose $\mathrm{pv}(1/x)$ into regular and singular distributions, but that doesn't convince me that it's impossible. For example, [Hörmann & Steinbauer](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~stein/lehre/SoSem09/distrvo.pdf) on page 134 say, that the singular support of $\mathrm{pv}(1/x)$ is $\{0\}$ and $1/x |_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}}$ is a regular distribution.

Comment: No canonical (even less unique) decomposition exists. In particular there is no distribution $f$ supported at $\{0\}$ such that $pv(1/x)-f$ is $L^1_{loc}$. Any distribution is locally the $k$-th derivative of a continuous function, that's quite the best we can say.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please elaborate on that last part? What does it mean that that distributions are locally the $k$-th derivative of a continuous function?

Comment: Take any $\phi \in C^\infty_c, \int \phi=1$, let $\psi_n = \phi \ast 1_{[n,n+1]}$, then any distribution $T=\sum_n T \psi_n$ is a sum of compactly supported distributions, $T \psi_n$ has finite order $k_n$, so $T \psi_n=f_n^{(k_n+1)}$ with $f_n$ continuous and $T=\sum_n f_n^{(k_n+1)}$. Tempered distributions are better behaved because $k_n $ is bounded. For $T=\sum_n \delta^{(n)}(.-n)$ then $k_n$ is unbounded. What do you get if you apply  Lebesgue's decomposition theorem to $f_n'$ ?